# Usage of question: How does it look like from your side?

Tags: word-usage

> How does it look like from your side?

It is often used at communication with customer when asking how they are or how it looks like/what they think, if they already finished etc.

For example:

> I have finished maintaining the data. How does it look like from your side?

Is this word "side" the correct one? Shouldn't I use:

> How does it look like from your part/point?

Comment: "side" is being used as a synonym for "point of view".

Comment: It's essentially a metaphor, treating each participant in the conversation as being on different sides of a wall or window.

Answer (score 1):

[Barmar](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/66603/barmar)'s comment is correct:

> It's essentially a metaphor, treating each participant in the conversation as being on different sides of a wall or window.

I picture something like this:

[image]

Obviously people one side can't see at all from the other side, just like how a remote maintainer can't see what's going on on the client's computer.

Your other options sound weird to me:

> 1. *How does it look from your part?

(1) doesn't scan, although I could probably figure it out from context.

> 2. How does it look from your point?

Do you mean "point of view"? Otherwise this isn't colloquial English either.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you’re talking not just about different but about clearly rival points of view, ‘your side’ is very much better than ‘your part/point’

‘part’ or ‘point’ could fit there, but not nearly as easily.

Meanwhile, it’s either ‘How does it look from your side?’ or ‘What does it look like from your side?’ Does the make sense, please?